# Why can't I see the favicon despite setting the manifest?

Tags: webpack, frontend, favicon, manifest.json

I am developing a React page without CRA. I need to set a favicon and a service worker. So, I set up a web manifest, but the favicon is not displayed. How can I fix it ?

The environment was built with Webpack and React. I've tried adding the `favicons-webpack-plugin` and adding a favicon property at `html-webpack-plugin`.

```
{
  "short_name": "DSM DMS",
  "name": "DSM-DMS Daedeok Software Meister-highschool - Dormitory Management System",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./public/favicon.png",
      "sizes": "192x192 168x168 144x144 96x96 72x72 64x64 48x48 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
const WebpackPwaManifest = require('webpack-pwa-manifest');
const ManifestConfig = require('manifest.json');
//...
plugins: [...,new Webpack(ManifestConfig),...]
//...
```

I thought that if I set a manifest, I can show the favicon, but it doesn't. Console in Chrome developer tool doesn't throw any error. Application/Manifest normally shows us the icons and no errors as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a favicon you do not need a web manifest. Simply copy the image into the public folder and make sure the file is named `favicon.ico`.

The icons array in the web manifest is used to display the icon once the user installed the PWA on the mobile device.

Have a [look at this article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa), where I explain in detail the different web manifest properties and how to set it up properly,